# login using curl not working with captcha

Tags: php, curl

> I am trying to get my home page after login using CURL but I don't
>   know why it is not displayed. I think something is wrong in my code;
>   please check my code and let me know whats wrong in this code

i tried every thing but fails every time but i seen that it is possible to login in this website, i have one software that successfully login but its is trial version and i wanted to build same thing in PHP

```
<?php 
$file_contents=file_get_contents("https://www.irctc.co.in/eticketing/loginHome.jsf");
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($file_contents);

$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
$imgs = $xpath->query('//*[@id="cimage"]');
foreach($imgs as $img)
{
    $imagesrc=$img->getAttribute('src') . PHP_EOL;
}
?>

<?php
//initial request with login data
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
      $user='ansari4all';
      $pass='ansari4all';
      $captcha=$_REQUEST['j_captcha'];
      $submit=$_REQUEST['submit'];
      $ch = curl_init();

      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.irctc.co.in/eticketing/loginHome.jsf');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.107 Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "j_username=$user&j_password=$pass&j_captcha=$captcha&submit=$submit");
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie-name');  //could be empty, but cause problems on some hosts
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/var/www/ip4.x/file/tmp');  //could be empty, but cause problems on some hosts
      $answer = curl_exec($ch);
      if (curl_error($ch)) {
          echo curl_error($ch);
      }

      //another request preserving the session

      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.irctc.co.in/eticketing/home');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
      echo $answer = curl_exec($ch);
      if (curl_error($ch)) {
          echo curl_error($ch);
      }
}
?>
<form method="post">
    <img src="https://www.irctc.co.in/eticketing/<?php echo $imagesrc;?>" />
    captcha:<input type="text" name="j_captcha" />
    <input id="loginbutton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"  />   
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot login to the site with my browser, it everytime says

[image]

Seems to be an error of the page. If not, you should get the image URL and the image itself with cURL and use the session as with your POST request. This is very important for some captchas.

Comment: you are saying that "use the session as with your POST request" can you please explain this? i am not able to understood what you are trying to say please elaborate it.